# Javascript multiple condition array filter

Tags: javascript, filtering

I need help putting together an array search that is based on multiple conditions.  Furthermore, all the conditions are conditional, meaning I may or may not need to filter on those conditions.  What I have:

Array of objects to filter:

```
var data = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 3,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2016-07-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 4,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 5,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category3",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c152g2"),
    "transid" : 6,
    "acct" : "acct3",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2016-10-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category3",
    "amount" : 103
}]
```

I am filtering the above array of objects based on another array of mixed elements.  The elements represent the following search fields:

- "searchstring": to search on all fields in the data array for any
  matched text sequence
- object with key values reprsenting account type and a  true or false
  for value indicating if it should be used to filter
- startdate to filter transdate on
- enddate to filter transdate
- category name to filter category on

The array that has the search conditions looks like this (but if some of the fields are not necessary they will be set to undefined or just an empty string or array):

```
var filtercondition = {
    "p",
    {acct1:true,acct2:false,acct3:true...}
    "2016-06-01",
    "2016-11-30",
    "category3"
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?  What I've devised is a separate search for each element in the filter array, but this seems non optimal and very tedious.  I'm open to a redesign of my setup...

Comment: What is the expected size of the data? Where is it expected to run? recent computers? mobile? old computers? strong servers? The "best way" really depends on multiple factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// You wrote that it's an array, so changed the braces 
var filtercondition = ["p",
{acct1:true,acct2:false,acct3:true...}
"2016-06-01",
"2016-11-30",
"category3"
];

var filtered = data.filter(o => {
    if(filtercondition[0] && !o.category.includes(filtercondition[o])) { // checking just the category, but you can check if any of more fields contains the conditions 
        return false;
    }
    if(filtercondition[1]) {
        for(var key in filtercondition[1]) {
        if(filtercondition[1][key] === true && o.acct != key) {
            return false;
        }
        }
    }
    if(filtercondition[2] && o.transdate < filtercondition[2]) {
        return false;
    }
    if(filtercondition[3] && o.transdate > filtercondition[3]) {
        return false;
    }
    if(filtercondition[4] && o.category !== filtercondition[4]) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Two notes:
   - changed the braces of `filtercondition` so that it is an array, however I would suggest to use an object instead.
   - this `{acct1:true,acct2:false,acct3:true...}` sample doesn't make sense for me, since it suggests that the `acct` field should be `acct1` and `acct3` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me. I made a slight edit to your suggested code to "return true" in case where all the other conditions fail because otherwise nothing is returned.

Answer (score 9):

Create an array of functions, each function representing a condition.

Here's some sample code which demonstrates the approach...

```
 var conditions = [];

 // Dynamically build the list of conditions
 if(startDateFilter) {
    conditions.push(function(item) { 
       return item.transdate >= startDateFilter.startDate;
    });
 };

 if(categoryFilter) {
     conditions.push(function(item) {
         return item.cateogry === categoryFilter.category;
     });
 };
 // etc etc
```

Once you have an array of conditions, you can use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to run each condition on an item.

```
 var itemsMatchingCondition = data.filter(function(d) {
     return conditions.every(function(c) {
         return c(d);
     });
 });
```

Or, using the more compact arrow functions:

```
const itemsMatchingCondition = data.filter(d => conditions.every(c => c(d));
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll want to use brackets for your array not curly braces:

```
var filtercondition = [
    "p",
    {acct1:true,acct2:false,acct3:true...},
    "2016-06-01",
    "2016-11-30",
    "category3"
];
```

Then again, I don't think that an array is the best data type for that. Try an object like this:

```
var filtercondition = {
    query: "p",
    accounts: {acct1:true,acct2:false,acct3:true...},
    date1: "2016-06-01",
    date2: "2016-11-30",
    category: "category3"
};
```

Then, try using Array.prototype.filter:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(obj) {
    for (var key in filtercondition) {
        // if condition not met return false
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a bunch of small granular functions and compose them.

```
//only some utilities, from the top of my mind
var identity = v => v;

//string-related
var string = v => v == null? "": String(v);
var startsWith = needle => haystack => string(haystack).startsWith(needle);
var endsWith = needle => haystack => string(haystack).endsWith(needle);
var contains = needle => haystack => string(haystack).contains(needle);

//do sth with an object
var prop = key => obj => obj != null && prop in obj? obj[prop]: undefined;
var someProp = fn => obj => obj != null && Object.keys(obj).some(k => fn(k) );
var someValue = fn => obj => obj != null && Object.keys(obj).some(k => fn(obj[k]) );

//logic
var eq = b => a => a === b;
var not = fn => function(){ return !fn.apply(this, arguments) };
var and = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => function(){
        return a.apply(this, arguments) && b.apply(this, arguments);
    });

var or = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => function(){
        return a.apply(this, arguments) || b.apply(this, arguments);
    });

//composition
var compose = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => v => return a(b(v)));
var chain = (...funcs) => funcs.reduceRight((a, b) => v => return a(b(v)));

//and whatever else you want/need
//but stay granular, don't put too much logic into a single function
```

and an example composition:

```
var filterFn = and(
    //some value contains "p"
    someValue(contains("p")),

    //and
    chain(
        //property "foo"
        prop("foo"), 
        or(
            //either contains "asdf"
            contains("asdf"),

            //or startsWith "123"
            startsWith("123")
        )
    ),
)
```

since I don't know how you build your filterconditions, I cannot tell you exactly how to parse them into such a composition, but you could compose them like this:

```
//start with something basic, so we don't ever have to check wether filterFn is null
var filterFn = identity;

//and extend/compose it depending on some conditions
if(/*hasQuery*/){
    filterFn = and(
        // previous filterFn(obj) && some value on obj contains `query`
        filterFn,
        someValue(contains(query)))
    )
}

if(/*condition*/){
    //extend filterFn
    filterFn = or(
        // (obj.foo === null) || previous filterFn(obj)
        chain(prop("foo"), eq(null)),
        filterFn
    );
}
```

and so on

Comment: the cleanest solution! Bravo 

Comment: just a small typo in ``var eq => a => b => a === b;`` it should be ``var eq = a => b => a === b;``. Same thing with ``not`` ;)

Comment: @bflemi3 it depends. Yes, ramda provides these methods, but it comes with a lot more. May be useful or may be just bloat. And the API tries to be flexible, things like currying ..., but that comes at a cost. Now take a look at the methods above. Some are basically "operators" in disguise; I'm not sure you want "cost" in something that basic. So, ramda may be useful if you need most of what it provides, including the flexibility. If you don't, it might be overkill; bloat your app or in the worst case even slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

First, some points:

- Your `data` object is invalid if you're going to use it in the browser. Probably the data comes from `MongoDB`, right? Your  backend (data source) should have a method to encode it properly and remove `ObjectID` and `ISODate` references.
- Your `filtercondition` is not a valid JavaScript object/JSON. Check my example.

So, you can filter your data array with [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Something like that:

```
let data = [{
    "_id" : "583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6",
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : "2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z",
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : "583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6",
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : "2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z",
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : "583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6",
    "transid" : 5,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : "2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z",
    "category" : "category3",
    "amount" : 103
}];


let filterToApply = {
    acct: {
        acct1: true,
        acct2: false,
        acct3: true
    },
    initialDate: "2016-06-01",
    finalDate: "2016-11-30",
    category: "category3"
}


let filterData = (array, filter) => {

    return array.filter( (item) => {

        /* here, you iterate each item and compare with your filter,
           if the item pass, you must return true. Otherwise, false */


        /* e.g.: category check (if present only) */
        if (filter.category && filter.category !== item.category) 
            return false;
        }

        /* add other criterias check... */ 

        return true;
});

}

let dataFiltered = filterData(data, filterToApply);
console.log(dataFiltered);
```

Comment: `So, you can sort your data array with Array#filter method.` Array#filter doesn't Array#sort ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter an array with multiple conditions and the conditions may be optional, then use the following method.

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'John', age: 25, city: 'New York' },
    { name: 'John', age: 25, city: 'New' },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 32, city: 'Los Angeles' },
    { name: 'Bob', age: 45, city: 'New York' },
    { name: 'Alice', age: 38, city: 'Los Angeles' }
];

const filteredData = (n, c, a) => data.filter(item => {
    if (n || c || a) {
         return (n ? item.name === n : true) && (c ? item.city === c : true) && (a ? item.age === a : true); // keep adding conditons as much as u want
    }
});


console.log(filteredData('John', null, 25));
console.log(filteredData(null, 'Los Angeles', 38));
console.log(filteredData(null, 'Los Angeles', null));
```

You can chain as many as conditions